# cfpresentation notes disappear on powerpoint export

Tags: coldfusion, powerpoint

Trying to export a powerpoint presentation from coldfusion. It works, but the notes disappear when exported.

```
<cfpresentation format="ppt" destination="#CurrentDir#\trialCerts1.ppt" showNotes="yes" title="All Certificates" overwrite="yes">

<!---The code for the first slide--->

<cfpresentationslide title="welcome to the first slide" notes="here are some notes">
<p> Here is some information </p>
</cfpresentationslide> 

<!---The code for the second slide--->
<cfpresentationslide title="Conclusion" notes="Special thanks to Lori and Jeff for contributing their art and expertise."> 
    <h1>Great Job Team!</h1> 
    <p>Some info here</p> 
    </cfpresentationslide> 

</cfpresentation>
```